# scala sum list of numeric values

Tags: scala

I want a generic function to sum values in a list.

The following code does not compile:

```
def sum[T : Numeric](x: List[T]): T = {
    if(x.isEmpty) 0
    else x.head + sum(x.tail)

  }
```

The compilation error is:

```
error: type mismatch;

[INFO]  found   : Int(0) 

[INFO]  required: T

[INFO]     if(x.isEmpty) 0
```

Comment: Why not just use `x.sum` (where `x` is a `List[T]` and `T` has an implicit `Numeric[T]` instance defined)?

Comment: I encountered the code snip online and was curious as to how I could make it more generic. It's an exercise in understanding scala (I'm not at school, just curious)

Comment: BTW, one thing to beware of with this type of function: it's not _tail recursive_. If you have a very long list, you can get a _stack overflow_. (Now where have I heard that expression before?) For a function to be tail recursive, the recursive call must be the last expression.

Comment: @MIke Allen, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error is telling you that you've specified the return type is `T`, but you're always returning a `0` for an empty list, which is an `Int`. What if the passed-in list contains something else, i.e. `T` is `Double` or some custom type? Try this:

```
if(x.isEmpty) implicitly[Numeric[T]].zero
```

Full working method:

```
def sum[T : Numeric](x: List[T]): T = {
  if (x.isEmpty) implicitly[Numeric[T]].zero
  else implicitly[Numeric[T]].plus(x.head, sum(x.tail))
}
```

Or:

```
def sum[T](x: List[T])(implicit num: Numeric[T]): T = {
  import num._
  if (x.isEmpty) zero
  else x.head + sum(x.tail)
}
```

Comment: You're missing `implicitly[Numeric[T]].plus` also! ;)

Comment: yes, because otherwise:   error: type mismatch;
[INFO]  found   : List[T]
[INFO]  required: List[String]
[INFO]     else x.head + sum(x.tail)

Comment: except now I get "cannot resolve symbol 'implicitly'"

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a million. Really appreciate it

Comment: Correct, you have to be sure to use the Numeric's addition. I've edited to include full examples that work for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
def sum[T](x: List[T])(implicit num: Numeric[T]): T = x.foldLeft(num.zero)(num.plus)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce` (if you don't want to setup inital value for sum) otherwise use `fold` operation:

```
def sumWithReduce[T](lst: List[T])(implicit numericType: Numeric[T]):T 
= lst.reduce(numericType.plus)

def sumWithFold[T](lst: List[T])(implicit numericType: Numeric[T]):T 
= lst.fold(numericType.zero)(numericType.plus)
```

Comment: `reduce` fails for empty lists, `fold` is more robust.