# How to make a function to work with a collection of any Numeric type in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I would like to create a function that can take any Collection: List, Array ... of any type and sum the values inside. I tried something like this. But Using AnyVal instead of Double does not work well

```
class SumNumbers {
}

object  SumNumbers{
  def sum(collection: LinearSeq[Double]): Double  ={
  collection match {
  case Nil => 0.0
  case head:: tail => head + sum(tail)
 }}
}


object MainT {
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
   val x = SumNumbers.sum(List(0, 1, 3, 4))
   println(x)
 }}
```

Answer (score 3):

Following your basic design.

```
def sum[N:Numeric](collection: Iterable[N]): Double = {
  import Numeric.Implicits._
  if (collection.isEmpty) 0.0
  else collection.head.toDouble + sum(collection.tail)
}
```

Works for collection types `Array`, `List`, `Seq`, `Vector`, and more.

Works for numeric types `Double`, `Float`, `Long`, `Int`, `Short`, `Char`, and `Byte`.

If you want to return the same numeric type as that being summed:

```
def sum[N:Numeric](collection: Iterable[N]): N = {
  import Numeric.Implicits._
  if (collection.isEmpty) implicitly[Numeric[N]].zero
  else collection.head + sum(collection.tail)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically want [**Polymorphism**](https://gist.github.com/BalmungSan/c19557030181c0dc36533f3de7d7abf4), which is the ability to apply the same operation to multiple types.

It turns out that in this case, one of the best approaches is a [**Typeclass**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html), due to its flexibility to accept external types.

If you would only wanted to accept any number, then you would only need to use the [`Numeric`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html) typeclass that  is part of the stdlib; as has already been shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735685/scala-sum-list-of-numeric-values) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302982/how-to-set-type-parameter-bound-in-scala-to-make-generic-function-for-numerics).

However, since you also want to abstract over the collection type you may need to either combine that plus subtyping polymorhism using the `Seq` trait.
Or, you could turn this into the next level by also providing a typeclass for collections.

If you are open to use the [**cats** library](https://typelevel.org/cats/), you could just use `Monoid` for the combination part and `Foldable` for the itaration *(folding)* part.

```scala
import cats.{Foldable, Monoid}
import cats.syntax.all._

def usingCats[C[_] : Foldable, A : Monoid](data: C[A]): A =
  data.combineAll
```

Which can be used like this:

```scala
import scala.collection.immutable.ArraySeq

val ints = List(1, 2, 3)
val doubles = ArraySeq(0.0d, 5.0d, 10.0d)
val strings = LazyList("A", "B", "C")

usingCats(ints) // res: Int = 6
usingCats(doubles) // res: Double = 15.0
usingCats(strings) // res: String = ABC
```

But, you can also implement it by yourslef:
*(but you would be repeating a lot of code that is already provided by the library)*

```scala
trait MyFoldable[C[_]] {
  def fold[A, B](ca: C[A])(z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B
}
object MyFoldable {
  implicit final val MyFoldableList: MyFoldable[List] =
    new MyFoldable[List] {
      override def fold[A, B](list: List[A])(z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B =
        list.foldLeft(z)(op)
    }
  
  implicit final val MyFoldableArraySeq: MyFoldable[ArraySeq] =
    new MyFoldable[ArraySeq] {
      override def fold[A, B](arr: ArraySeq[A])(z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B =
        arr.foldLeft(z)(op)
    }
  
  implicit final val MyFoldableLazyList: MyFoldable[LazyList] =
    new MyFoldable[LazyList] {
      override def fold[A, B](lazyList: LazyList[A])(z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B =
        lazyList.foldLeft(z)(op)
    }
}

trait MyMonoid[A] {
  def empty: A
  def combine(a1: A, a2: A): A
}
object MyMonoid {
  implicit final val MyMonoidInt: MyMonoid[Int] =
    new MyMonoid[Int] {
      override final val empty: Int = 0
      
      override final def combine(i1: Int, i2: Int): Int =
        i1 + i2
    }
  
  implicit final val MyMonoidDouble: MyMonoid[Double] =
    new MyMonoid[Double] {
      override final val empty: Double = 0.0d
      
      override final def combine(d1: Double, d2: Double): Double =
        d1 + d2
    }
  
  implicit final val MyMonoidString: MyMonoid[String] =
    new MyMonoid[String] {
      override final val empty: String = ""
      
      override final def combine(s1: String, s2: String): String =
        s1 + s2
    }
}

def byHand[C[_], A](data: C[A])
                   (implicit foldable: MyFoldable[C], monoid: MyMonoid[A]): A =
  foldable.fold(data)(monoid.empty)(monoid.combine)
```

Which would produce the same results:

```scala
byHand(ints) // res: Int = 6
byHand(doubles) // res: Double = 15.0
byHand(strings) // res: String = ABC
```

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/nyIVa0oCRmaQcHzc8ELJeA/9)*.